# How to add two filter or Sorting properties for single column...If a column is binded with two infoObjects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sapui5

How can we add two info objects in one column customdata aggregation....Suppose in above answer we have stated filter property as "Description" And If I want to state two two filter properties like I want to filter by using description as well as by using key as well....But I can't add two filterproperties in column....Like filterProperty : "Description", filterProperty : "Key".
So what will be good approach for that?`your text`
Here is the code for reference

```xml
<Column id="col_colViewP" 
    hAlign="Left" 
    visible="false" 
    <customData>
        <core:CustomData key="p13nData" 
            value='\{"columnKey": "EDACVWTPF_T", "type":"string", "maxLength": "20", "filterProperty": "EDACVWTPF_T", "sortProperty": "EDACVWTPF_T", "leadingProperty": "EDACVWTPF_T"}'/>
    </customData>
    <Text id="colEDACVWTPF" 
        text="{i18n>viewTypeLbl}"/>
</Column>
```

```xml
<Text id="EDACVWTPF" 
    text="{TableMlstJsonModel>EDACVWTPF_T}{TableMlstJsonModel>EDACVWTIM_T}">
</Text>
```

Good approach to add two sorting properties.